# Java code/library to calculate the earth mover's distance

Tags: java, algorithm, distance, histogram

I'm looking for java code (or a library) that calculates the [earth mover's distance (EMD)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance) between two histograms. This could be directly or indirectly (e.g. using the Hungarian algorithm). I found several implementations of this in c/c++ (e.g. ["Fast and Robust Earth Mover's Distances"](http://www.cs.huji.ac.il/~ofirpele/FastEMD/), but I'm wondering if there is a Java version readily available.

I will be using the EMD calculation to evaluate the approach given by [this paper](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=1920841.1920944) in the context of a science project I'm working on.

**Update**

Using a variety of resources I estimate that the code below should do the trick. *determineMinCostAssignment* is the calculation of the optimal assignment as determined by the Hungarian algorithm. For this I will be using the code from http://konstantinosnedas.com/dev/soft/munkres.htm
My main concern is the calculated *flow*: I am not sure if this is correct. Is there someone who can verify that this is correct or not?

```
    /**
 * Determines the Earth Mover's Distance between two histogram assuming an equal distance between two buckets of a histogram. The distance between
 * two buckets is equal to the differences in the indexes of the buckets.
 * 
 * @param threshold
 *          The maximum distance to use between two buckets.
 */
public static double determineEarthMoversDistance(double[] histogram1, double[] histogram2, int threshold) {
    if (histogram1.length != histogram2.length)
        throw new InvalidParameterException("Each histogram must have the same number of elements");

    double[][] groundDistances = new double[histogram1.length][histogram2.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < histogram1.length; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < histogram2.length; ++j) {
            int abs_diff = Math.abs(i - j);
            groundDistances[i][j] = Math.min(abs_diff, threshold);
        }
    }

    int[][] assignment = determineMinCostAssignment(groundDistances);
    double costSum = 0, flowSum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < assignment.length; i++) {
        double cost = groundDistances[assignment[i][0]][assignment[i][1]];
        double flow = histogram2[assignment[i][1]];
        costSum += cost * flow;
        flowSum += flow;
    }
    return costSum / flowSum;
}
```

Comment: Optimal transportation cost is obviously a linear problem with linear constraints. Any linear optimization library (interior point methods work well) will do (btw, what does the Hungarian algorithm do here ? You are not looking for integer solutions). Other keywords to search for are "Monge-Kantorovich distance", "Wasserstein distance", or "Optimal transportation". There are also algorithms based on convex optimization (where you directly find convex conjugate pairs phi, phi^* for the dual Kantorovich problem; best for continuous spaces).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a pure Java port of the FastEMD algorithm, that I just released:
https://github.com/telmomenezes/JFastEMD

Comment: Great! And just in time as well, since I was just preparing to distribute it to some other people to verify the results

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use for Java/Scala:

```
import org.apache.commons.math3.ml.distance.EarthMoversDistance
new EarthMoversDistance().compute(observed, expected)
```

Answer (score 1):

The website ["Fast and Robust Earth Mover's Distances"](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~ofirpele/FastEMD/code/) has a Java wrapper for the C/C++ code with compiled binary for Linux and Windows.

Comment: I know (I added the compiled binary for windows myself), but I'm still hoping that there is a full java version available somewhere. That would allow me to transfer the complete experiments code to others with a little less explanation.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/wihoho/VideoRecognition

- Adapt the author's [C implementation](http://www.cs.duke.edu/~tomasi/software/emd.htm) with python module through a file interface
- The modified C codes are under the folder EarthMoverDistance SourceCode

I am pretty sure that you can do the same thing with Java. Just add a file interface to connect the C implementation of EMD with your Java codes.